# TFS Build - "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We have a legacy solution (>300 projects across several solutions) currently running in the old Xaml build definitions. I'm trying to convert it to the vNext build definitions, but I'm having intermittent errors.

Every so often, a file in the process will become locked, and cause the build to throw the following error:

> CSC (0, 0) Metadata file 'E:\Builds\1\3\a\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' could not be opened -- The process cannot access the file 'xxx.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Its a different file every time (this latest was Newtonsoft.json.dll - a nuget package), and not always the same solution. Subsequent builds will work fine.

I've tried to resolve this by adding `/NodeReuse:false` to the build arguments, and whilst it appears to have reduced the frequency a little, it still hasn't resolved the issue.

Due to the nature of the build, and the fact it relies on the projects outputting to a common location (projects use a combination of File and Project references), I have the following settings configured:

`/p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)" /p:ReferencePath="$(build.stagingDirectory)" /NodeReuse:False`

It's almost always the Staging Directory that these dlls are located within.

Reconfiguring the product to exclusively use Project References is unfortunately not viable at this time.

Is there something I can do to the build step to eliminate these locking issues?

Comment: Just a thought dont know if that will solve it but worth a try , try cleaning the $(build.stagingDirectory). (checkbox on the build step)

Comment: @WojtekT Unfortunately that wouldn't work. Solution A depends on the output from Solution B and so on. Cleaning the Staging Directory would wipe out the necessary files.

Comment: I assume you have multiple build solution steps, If you would clean the directory in the first build it would get rid of the files that are there and would not have any input to your other solutions. Just another thought :)

Comment: @WojtekT I can give it a shot, but as far as I can see, the staging directory is automatically wiped out at the start of each build.

Comment: Could you figure out the dlls was used/locked by which process? Kill all the processes that maybe consuming your compiled code in task manager. Alternatively, you could download [Lockhunter][1] and see which program is locking that file.

Comment: In my case it was a rogue xcopy command that was occuring during a post build event in one of my projects that wasn't supposed to be happening on the build server.  LockHunter helped me trace it down.

Comment: Maybe this is caused by projects referencing the same dll and getting build in parallel

Comment: Same here - I was going to suggest changing the build to *not* run in parallel. Changing this fixed it for me...